# log in security problem

Tags: login, security

I logged in to my ubuntu desktop , (dual boot with win10), with just pressing "cancel" on log in screen instead of my password, how is that possible?

Comment: Hmmm. When I press Cancel on a freshly-installed stock 18.10 test system, I get the correct behavior: I don't get logged in. How is your setup different from mine?

Comment: yup, that`s the correct behavior, i`m baffled ..mine is latest update/upgrade..

Comment: also repeated the bug few times to make sure

Comment: after i did the network reset on windows 10 ,ubuntu returned to normal booting (did not get in w/o pass)..very strange situation, if anyone have any idea what's going on i would like to hear it..i even have a video of it